# z-index property not working [Nativescript]

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to place a circle above a line . I am trying to do it with z-index property . first time when the page is loaded it works fine.
But when i move to another component and come back, the circle goes down the line.

I am attaching the link for the screenshot along with this:
When first loaded:

[image]

when we move from it and come back:

[image]

Comment: It works on my end, may be it's a specific senario where it fails or even bug with code. So would you mind creating a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: What is the code you're using to set the z-index? in which function you put it?

Comment: I just set it in CSS.

Comment: @bks i put the code in css itself. i tried putting inline also.

Comment: @Manoj  I will try to put the code in playground and get back to you

Comment: Perhaps you should change the css property each time you enter the page, i personally do things like that by placing         `this._page.on(Page.navigatingToEvent, () => { /* your code */ })` inside the constructor

Comment: @Manoj https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=tp9ZtX . this is a sample code of the issue am facing. I want the circle on the line to be top on it

Answer (score 1):

Native layouts work bit different than HTML. The z-index you set is valid only within it's parent element not across the page. You are setting z-index on a element inside ListView item so anything within that item will only respect the z-index.

Looking at your code, you don't seem to need z-index if you just move your ListView after circle declaration or circle & line could be part of your item template itself.